# Extracting data from cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, parameters

I've looked at the similar questions but none of them directly apply to my situation.

It's a quite simple scenario.

I'm using parameter files, and while extracting a small 2x1 array from the pf file, I am left with

```
var_1 = 

[-180]
[-120]
```

I want to be able to treat the contents of var_1 like a matrix, but the brackets don't allow for me to do so. For instance, **sum(var_1)** returns an error.

How can I make it so that **var_1** becomes a matrix?

Thanks a lot,

Gauss

Comment: Just use `cell2mat` to convert it to a matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of cell arrays they are indexed using curl brackets '{' and '}'. In your case:

-180 is var_1{1} and -120 is var_1{2}.

As you can create matrices by concatenating variables using the square brackets '[' and ']'. Therefore you can create the matrix var_1 by:

```
var_1=[var_1{1},var_1{2}];
```

Now var_1 is a matrix.

```
sum(var_1)
```

sum(var_1) will now result in -300;

If the size of the cell array that you extract is changing then you can use for loops or

```
var_1=[var_1{1:end}];
```

to produce the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, your second solution doesn't work. (the one that for loops)

Comment: @NeilnGauss could you elaborate? I suggested either using for loops OR var_1=[var_1{1:end}]

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

```
sum(cell2mat(var_1))
```

Or simply:

```
sum([var_1{:}])
```